# Pairing laptop with a monitor

Tags: graphics-card

I am considering a laptop with a 13" display and 2G graphics card. I intend to get a 24" monitor to use as an external display, not as an extended display (no room on the desk) but down the road I might be using both the built-in and external at the same time.

This is for office work primarily. I will do minimal video and gaming.

It will be win 10 and Linux.

Trying to understand if the graphics card with 2G is enough for 1920x1080 on both displays.

Also, what spec on the monitor do I need to pay attention to in order to make sure it can work with this laptop?

Comment: For just "driving" a 1920*1080 display a 128 or 256MB graphics card is enough, it's the programs you run that mean you might need more. Web browsers now use GPU acceleration which can chew up memory...

Answer (score 0):

A 2GB dedicated graphics card should be more than enough for displaying the contents on a couple 1920 x 1080 monitors. You basically just need to make sure that your laptop has an HDMI port (Many new laptops don't) and that both, the laptop and the external screen is of high resolution(your preference on how much is high). Usually the graphics card that comes with your laptop can handle much more resolution than your laptop's max.